# What kinds of text file can be used in Weka StringToWordVector filter

Tags: java, filter, weka

I know the text file should be converted to arff file, but I am confused what content in text file? Is it totally a string, like "I am java", or like this

```
@relation 

@attribute  numerical
@attribute  numerical

@data
```

Text content "I am java"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert from a spreadsheet with instances (in raws) and the feature ( or attributes) values (in columns) to ARFF. The bulk of an ARFF file consists of a list of the instances, and the attribute values for each instance are separated by commas. Most spreadsheet and database programs allow you to export data into a file in comma-separated value (CSV) format as a list of records with commas between items. Having done this, you need only load the file into a text editor or word processor; add the dataset’s name using the @relation tag, the attribute information using @attribute, and an @data line; then save the file as raw text. Or upload your csv file in WEKA explorer (preprocess (open file as csv) and then save it as arff.

Comment: Thanks, I already got the solution with weka function. But one more question I am concerned is if I have the training dataset and are trained, I got the arff file with stringtowordvector function. If I want to use same features into test file, How can I do?

Comment: You can apply `StringToWordVector` both to the training and test datasets by using the batch option (`-b`) in the command line. See: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Batch+filtering. You can check how to match your training and test vocabularies in three different ways at: http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/mapping-vocabulary-from-train-to-test.html.